# Can't get Ubuntu 16.10 installation USB to boot Apollo Lake motherboard

Tags: kernel, iso

Trying to install Ubuntu 16.10 on an Apollo lake motherboard (Asrock j3455b-itx). Can't get it to boot. Have tried several distorts to no avail- black screen with an unblinking cursor.

I read somewhere that j3455 requires kernel 4.7 or greater so I thought Ubuntu 16.10 (with kernel 4.8) would work, but it's doing the same thing as all the others.

Has anyone had any experience with this that can help me?

Thanks,
Avery

Edit: USB drives were created using Rufus 2.11 on Windows 10. Manjaro 17 alpha 2 worked, and also Manjaro 16.10.3 respun with 4.8 kernel (for those not familiar, it's an Arch derivative).

Solution: The first answer worked for me - in the BIOS, going to BOOT --> CSM and changing USB to Legacy Support.  Please give him a vote if you see this.

Please note:  This motherboard *still* requires a 4.7 or greater kernel to operate correctly. The solution mentioned just adds compatibility required for many distros to boot.

To solve the kernel issue, one can either use a distro that uses a 4.7+ kernel, or create a custom ISO.  I created a custom live USB of Mint 18.1 with 4.9 kernel by following this guide: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1784

Comment: Yes, 16.10 should work. How did you make the USB? Please edit your quesrtion and add that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `CSM` to `Enabled` in the motherboard's UEFI, under Boot menu (along with that, I have set `Legacy only` value for all 3 options below it) and then create the bootable drive using either MBR or GPT partition table.

Answer (score 1):

No need to enable legacy BIOS, as GRUB is the problem, see [here for analysis of the problem](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/jumper-ezbook-3-pro-can%27t-boot-from-usb-most-of-common-linux-distros-4175605766/page2.html).

To prepare a working USB drive try `isorespin.sh` script with (at least) `--apollo` switch.

See: [Customizing Ubuntu ISOs: Documentation and examples of how to use 'isorespin.sh'](http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/06/customizing-ubuntu-isos-documentation.html).

Then, once installed, install again [the rEFInd Boot Manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).
maybe use Windows working install or some tweaking with the same live install you booted from, i.e., mount internal disk esp partition and manually copy and enable refind, check developer page for manual instructions - but keep in mind you need to operate on internal EFI partition not the one of the USB drive.

Alternatively, you can [download already respun ISOs](http://linuxminipcs.com/isos).

Answer (score 0):

No need to enable CSM Legacy BIOS Support on your J3455 Apollo Lake motherboard or manually rebuild installation images anymore

Format your USB key with GPT partition table, create a FAT filesystem on it, then burn 64bit Ubuntu onto a USB key with Unetbootin. In my case i used 19.04 Server alternative iso.

https://ubuntu.com/download/server -> alternative downloads = http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.04/release/

I imagine any recent Ubuntu iso will work.

Then you can use UEFI boot.

I also updated to the latest firmware 1.9 using online update from within the UEFI, not sure if that is necessary or not.