# Ubuntu Intel Apollo Lake Processor

Tags: system-installation

I need help in installing Ubuntu on Intel Apollo lake Processor, i have tried on two different models , but could not install Ubuntu.Once it show full installation and took me to Login screen, but show invalid credentials and when i reboot, it show no bootable media found.
There is no Legacy option in BIOS, because as per Intel Website this platform: Apollo lake does not Support Legacy in BIOS

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate  http://askubuntu.com/questions/872065/cant-get-ubuntu-16-10-installation-usb-to-boot-apollo-lake-motherboard

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate question. Please close thread.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my Chuwi Lapbook made with Apollo lake processors. Created a bootable USB and change the boot order in bios.Works great but I don't know if it's better to install an appropriate kernel. I saw this link but yet didn't try it. https://linuxminipcs.wordpress.com/ubuntu-18-04-2-lts-bionic-beaver/